# What does AssocMaxWallDurationPerJobLimit mean in slurm?

Tags: slurm

I submitted a job but I get:

```
               253       x86 brando_j miranda9 PD       0:00      1 (AssocMaxWallDurationPerJobLimit)
```

what does it mean?

My sbatch script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name="brando_job"
#SBATCH --output="main.sh.o%j.%N"
#SBATCH --partition=x86
#SBATCH --time=47:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32
#SBATCH --sockets-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=16
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=32000
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:a100:4
#SBATCH --export=ALL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the requested duration `#SBATCH --time=47:00:00` is too long with respect to the limitations on your account.

You can check that with

```
sacctmgr show user $USER withassoc format=account,user,partition,MaxWallDurationPerJob
```